# CodeBuild execution continues after build fails instead of stopping

Tags: build, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm building a CI/CD pipeline using git, codebuild and elastic beanstalk.

During codebuild execution when build fails due to syntax error of a test case, I see codebuild progress to next stage and ultimately go on to produce the artifacts.

My understanding was if the build fails, execution should stop. is this a correct behavior ?

Please see the buildspec below.

```yaml
    version: 0.2

    phases:
      install:
        commands:
          - echo Installing package.json..
          - npm install
          - echo Installing Mocha...
          - npm install -g mocha
      pre_build:
        commands:
          - echo Installing source NPM placeholder dependencies...
      build:
        commands:
          - echo Build started on `date`
          - echo Compiling the Node.js code
          - mocha modules/**/tests/*.js
      post_build:
        commands:
          - echo Build completed on `date`
    artifacts:
      files:
        - modules/*
        - node_modules/*
        - package.json
        - config/*
        - server.js
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

CodeBuild detects build failures by exit codes. You should ensure that your test execution returns a non-zero exit code on failure.

[`POST_BUILD` will always run as long as `BUILD` was also run](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/view-build-details.html#view-build-details-phases) (regardless of `BUILD`'s success or failure.) The same goes for `UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS`. This is so you can retrieve debug information/artifacts.

If you want to do something different in `POST_BUILD` depending on the success or failure of `BUILD`, you can test the [builtin environment variable `CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html), which is set to `1` if `BUILD` succeeded, and `0` if it failed.

Comment: I'm trying to use the same logic, but when my tests fail CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING still equals 1. Do you manually update this environment variable upon failing?

Comment: @DakotaHipp Make sure that whatever `buildspec.yml` command you're using to execute your tests returns a non-zero exit code on failure. `CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING` is informational only, changing it manually will not affect the build outcome.

Comment: I was forced to manually change the CODE_BUILD_SUCCEEDING variable upon test failure, then I am checking that variable at later steps with an if statement similar to the other answer.

Comment: I added a line to the post_build section and let the post_build fail.  The CodeBuild logs can provide you the details of the failure in the build section.

    `post_build:                                                                                                                                                                                   
     commands:                                                                                                                                                                                   
       - test "$CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING" = "1"`

Answer (score 14):

CodeBuild uses the environment variable CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING to show if the build process seems to go right.

the best way I found right now is to create a small script in the install secion and then alway use this like:

```
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo '#!/bin/bash' > /usr/local/bin/ok; echo 'if [[ "$CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING" == "0" ]]; then exit 1; else exit 0; fi' >> /usr/local/bin/ok; chmod +x /usr/local/bin/ok
  post_build:
    commands:
      - ok && echo Build completed on `date`
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the same logic, but when my tests fail CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING still equals 1. Do you manually update this environment variable upon failing?

Comment: Does your test case return a non zero return code? this is basically the requirement for it to change automatically.

Comment: Yeah, it fails with exit code 2. As of now, I am changing CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING manually. It works, but it would be better if the exit registered automatically.

Comment: That looks convoluted. `[[ $CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING = 1 ]] && echo Build completed on $(date)` is hardly longer and doesn't need a script.

Answer (score 13):

The **post_build** section is run even if the build section might fail. Expanding on the previous answers, you can use the variable `CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING` in the post_build section of the `buildspec.yml` file. You can make the post_build section to run *if and only if* the build section completed successfully. Below is an example of how this can be achieved:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION)
      - CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION="${CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION:-$IMAGE_TAG}"
      - IMAGE_TAG=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
      - IMAGE_URI="$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG"
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...
      - docker build -t $IMAGE_URI .
  post_build:
    commands:
      - bash -c "if [ /"$CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING/" == /"0/" ]; then exit 1; fi"
      - echo Build stage successfully completed on `date`
      - docker push $IMAGE_URI
      - printf '[{"name":"clair","imageUri":"%s"}]' "$IMAGE_URI" > images.json
artifacts:
  files: images.json
```

Comment: Surely, you meant `\"` instead of `/"` for escaping, right? I used backslash and it worked.

Answer (score 13):

add this in build section

```
build:
     on-failure: ABORT
```

Comment: IMHO this should be the accepted answer as it's what the official docs are saying => https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to point out that if you want the whole execution to stop when a command fails, you may specify the `-e` option:

- When running a bash file

  ```sh
    - /bin/bash -e ./commands.sh
  ```
- Or when running a set of commands/bash file

  ```sh
  #!/bin/bash

  set -e

  # ... commands
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The post_build stage will be executed and the artifacts will be produced. The post_build is good to properly shut down the build environment, if necessary, and the artifacts could be useful even if the build failed. E.g. extra logs, intermediate files, etc.

I would suggest to use post_build only for commands what are agnostic to the result of your build, and properly de-initialise the build environment. Otherwise you can just exclude that step.

Answer (score 1):

captainblack- I have used his bash command and it worked

bash -c "if [ /"$CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING/" == /"0/" ]; then exit 1; fi"

I have added bash command in the buildspec.yml file from where you want other pipelines to get trigger. so it would first check if that pipeline is getting successful, only then other pipelines that you have mentioned get released.

post_build:
commands:

```
  - bash -c "if [ /"$CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING/" == /"0/" ]; 
    then exit 1; fi"
  - aws codepipeline start-pipeline-execution --name pipelinename
  - aws codepipeline start-pipeline-execution --name pipelinename
  - aws codepipeline start-pipeline-execution --name pipelinename
```